# Pass MVC view value to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

I am displaying a value on my MVC view using a query string. For example ..

in my view I have:

```
<h3>Selected Game <%=Request["GameId"]%> </h3>
```

This displays the gameid selected by user on the view (via a query string)

Now I want to be able to use this value displayed on the view and run a query in the controller/service layer code. How can I pass this value to the controller.

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Use-querystring-variables-in-Asp-Net-MVC-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Request the same way from the controller.

```
string gameid = Request["GameId"];
```

I would caution you, however, about trusting values you get from the request.  This is where hackers like to strike, by entering their own values, which may not even be numbers.

Validate all data you get from the client, including querystring parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass it to the same controller .. The view is already rendered.  You seem to know about `ajax`, so it's just a simple matter of making another request.  Make an `ajax` request to the controller in question with the `GameId` parameter.